# I get a signing error when I add an image to Assets in the SwiftUI Tutorial

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I get a signing error when I add an image to Assets in the SwiftUI Tutorial

I'm working on the SwiftUI Tutorial, but when I add an image or JSON file to Assets, I get the following Sign Error.

```
CodeSign /Users/k~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.app (in target 'SwiftUIPractice' from project 'SwiftUIPractice')
    cd /Users/~~/project/SwiftUIPractice
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    
    Signing Identity:     "-"
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftUIPractice.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.build/SwiftUIPractice.app.xcent --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der /Users/~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.app

/Users/~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.app: replacing existing signature
/Users/~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/~~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftUIPractice-ctdnfoihimrfqeejvxgheakcfzfv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftUIPractice.app/Assets.car
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would delete the Derived Data and "Clean BuildFolder" under the "Product" menu in Xcode. Instructions for deleting the derived data are all over the web. see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thank you Comments! I have tried what you say, but problem was not solved...